# Possible for those who answer questions down-vote other correct answers

Tags: discussion

It is quite possible for someone who answers a question to down-vote another answer even if both answers are correct. This can be used to get an answer accepted over the other. Take for example, I can answer a question correctly and down-vote any other so that my answers will be accepted. Is this a loophole used by some people? I have seen correct answers being down-voted for no reason and no explanations.

Comment: The OP accepts an answer, not the voting system.

Comment: @zisoft: You are right, but I understand the statement of OP. The downvote *can* bias future readers, specifically when both answers are equally valid.

Comment: @Patrick: having been on the receiving end of unexplained down votes from time to time I must say that that effect is minimal; at least in my personal experience.

Comment: This is sometimes referred to as "strategic downvoting", see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17538/what-should-be-done-to-people-who-downvote-strategically and others. It's impossible to distinguish between a "honest downvote" and a "strategic downvote" (except for border cases, where the answers are basically the same), but you shouldn't mind about that too much anyhow.

Answer (score 7):

What you are observing is true.   A person who submits an answer can down vote your answer.

Who cares?  Why does this matter?   If your answer is a good one, it will receive other upvotes - the person who submitted their own answer and downvoted yours is just one person.   If you are here to help, then that one incident will be a blip in your "StackOverflow lifetime".

However, it's important to be very conscious that the idea that a downvote on a particular answer came from one of the other answerers is paranoid.   The downvote may have come from anyone who thought the answer was not useful.  It might not be useful because it says the same thing as another answer that was posted earlier, without adding anything, or it might be genuinely not useful.    It is paranoid to think that the downvote on your answer came from another answerer.   People hesitate to comment on their downvotes, because a common response from the person downvoted is aggression.  That doesn't mean the downvote is wrong.

Summary: sometimes another answerer may downvote other answers, but it is not a big deal.  Don't worry about it: just write good, original answers and let the system work.